# Automatically making a view controller initiate a segue transition

Tags: ios, xcode, segue, uiactivityindicatorview

I am still learning how to use Xcode, and one thing that I am curious to find more about has been how to get a loading screen (such as for downloading information from the web to core data) and transitioning to another view controller with a storyboard segue transition when done. Where could I find more information about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `ViewController` that you want to make the `segue` you can use the method:

```
-(void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString*)identifier sender:(id)sender
```

Check: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

This `segue` you are performing must be defined in your *.storyboard* file.

So you can create a segue in IB and when you need it to appear just call the method described above.

The *loading screen* you are looking for might be one HUD. As you can't use the one in iOS cause its a private API I recommend you to try something like this: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/atmhud or this: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mbprogresshud.

Comment: Thanks! Your info and the links were great resources!

Comment: When creating the segue, make sure to pull the segue from the actual view controller to the next view controller instead of from e.g. a UIButton. The typical loading spinners used are `UIActivityIndicatorView`s. To add a little detail to the question about doing this after you download content from the web, those kind of methods typically have a completion block argument, which is just a segment of code to be executed.